# Architectural recommendation to manage site during multi-country rollout

Tags: solution-architecture

Architecture Question

Not sure if it’s been asked before, I couldn’t find something similar what I have described below.

Well my question is during a multi country brand roll-out what is the best architectural recommendation to manage sites:

1)  **Creating each site as a separate node, where each node corresponds to a country**

- If each country site has a lot of similarities with en-US site, what would be the ideal way to create a country site by Copying or Cloning?

  [image]

2)  **Creating a market site as a subfolder under Parent brand site.**

- Would this approach be Helix Complaint or can it be made?

[image]

Comment: This is mainly an opinion based question. Please join the Sitecore slack channel at  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScsJX9PC3m8u-labRn_BNnByR0aiAxPYowN-doed6_t45aPhg/viewform or the Sitecore Community forum at community.sitecore.net

Comment: Take a look on Barend Emmerzaal's guide -> http://barendemmerzaal.com/downloads/Sitecore-SXA-site-structure-guide.pdf . It was made for Sitecore SXA module but could definitely answer your questions or guide you through the choice process.

Comment: Thanks Peter, i came across the link shared by you while doing more research on this subject. Thanks for sharing it here, might help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are seeking an opinion, opinions can differ based on your detailed requirements. If there is just one brand and you want to rollout in multiple countries, I would say

[image]

But if there could be multiple brands as well then I would say, go with multi tenancy(country wise)

[image]

As for Helix principals, you should be able to create multiple modules that are shared among different countries. However, you will have challenges with thems and frontend stuff if you want to use different themes and FE stuff. Well, we achieved this with another approach that might violate helix. We actually created a theme module for each country. That theme module contains themes and FE stuff for that country. Within this module, we created folder structure to represent different features.

Comment: Thanks for the viewpoint Syed.